# PHP Email Character Alignment

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, coding-style

I did the email function on php. but when I get the email is not align properly. Can anyone please help me to fix the issue. this part couldn't align properly, I don't have much knowlege on that.

```
What is Union Assurance brand pay off line              correct

What does the Union Assurance brand colour orange signify               correct

What does the Union Assurance brand colour grey signify                 wrong

Union Assurance is baked by             correct

Union Assurance Brand is built on the platform of               wrong

Union Assurance brand promise trust is delivered through                wrong

Union Assurance Symbol depicts          correct

What's Union Assurance brand ranked in the LMD Brands.          correct

What's Union Assurance brand value?             correct

What is the best way to build your brand                correct
```

---

```
<?php 

    $result = select("SELECT * FROM results
    ORDER BY userId DESC
    LIMIT 1");
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);


if($row['email']==''){
    echo "Email cannot be Send";

}
else{

    $mailTo=$row['email'];
    $name=$row['username'];
    $score=$row['score'];
    $to=$mailTo;

// Your subject
$subject="Union Assurance Questionnaire Result";

// From
$header="from: Union Assurance<unionassurance@ualink.lk>";

// Your message

$message="Dear $name,\r\n";
$message.="Thank you For Participate the  Union Assurance Questionnaire,\r\n\n";
$message.="your Score is: $score ";
$result2=select("SELECT questions FROM questions");
$qstId=1;


while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){


    if($row['question'.$qstId.'']=='correct'){

$message.="\n\n".$row2['questions'].":";
$message.="".$row['question'.$qstId.'']."";
}

else{


        $message.="\n\n".$row2['questions']."";
        $message.= "\t\t".$row['question'.$qstId.'']."";

    }
        $qstId++;
}

$message.="\n\n Thank you, \n Union Assurance IT Team";


// send email
$sentmail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);

// if your email succesfully sent
if($sentmail){
echo "Email Has Been Sent .";
}
else {
echo "Cannot Send Email ";

}
}


?>
```

Comment: You can teable-view layout and send it as html (not plain text).

Answer (score 0):

Send html. From [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

```
$to  = 'aidan@example.com';

// subject
$subject = 'Birthday Reminders for August';

// message
$message = '
<html>
<head>
  <title>Birthday Reminders for August</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Here are the birthdays upcoming in August!</p>
   <table>
     <tr>
       <th>Person</th><th>Day</th><th>Month</th><th>Year</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Joe</td><td>3rd</td><td>August</td><td>1970</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Sally</td><td>17th</td><td>August</td><td>1973</td>
     </tr>
   </table>
 </body>
 </html>
 ';

 // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
  $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
  $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";



 // Mail it   
 mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```